LDAP searching with java
I am connected to LDAP, but I don't know anything about the structure of it. How can I find out what baseDn is ?
final NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> result = context.search(
    "", "(objectClass=organizationalUnits)", controls);

tried this, but nothing returns


How can I find out what baseDn is ?

Normally it should have been given to you together with the other connection details.
Usually you can get it from the "rootDSE" entry; some LDAP libraries have a specific function to retrieve it, but you can always get it using a search operation:

Search base: "" (empty DN)

Search scope: BASE (this is important – SUB won't retrieve the rootDSE entry)

Search filter: (objectClass=*)

Requested attributes: either {"namingContexts"} or {"*", "+"}
(many servers have it as an 'operational' attribute, hidden by default)


The result entry will have a namingContexts attribute where each value specifies a valid base DN on that server. However, don't make this lookup every single time – generally the base DN is meant to be part of the static configuration.
